# vb.net instance of MemoryCache always returns Nothing from cache

Tags: .net, vb.net, caching, memorycache

I'm trying to create an instance of the MemoryCache class in order to cache some document information. Problem is that even though I don't get any exceptions the MemoryCache instance always returns 'Nothing'. I'm using the following bits of code;

Constructing the instance:

```
Private Shared ObjInfoCache As MemoryCache
Public Sub New()
    Dim CacheSettings As NameValueCollection = New NameValueCollection(3)
    CacheSettings.Add("CacheMemoryLimitMegabytes", 1024.ToString())
    CacheSettings.Add("physicalMemoryLimitPercentage", 50.ToString())
    CacheSettings.Add("pollingInterval", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2).ToString())
    ObjInfoCache = New MemoryCache("TestCache", CacheSettings)
End Sub
```

Code that saves/retrieves the information (which always jumps into the if statement):

```
arrayOfPropValues = ObjInfoCache(docID)
If arrayOfPropValues Is Nothing Then
    arrayOfPropValues = GetDocumentInfo(docID, arrayOfPropNames)
    ObjInfoCache.Add(docID, arrayOfPropValues, New CacheItemPolicy() With {.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(60)})
End If
```

Through testing I've found that using the default MemoryCache instance `ObjInfoCache = MemoryCache.Default` works perfectly. It however doesn't let me set the limit properties, which I'll need. I've also tried creating a new MemoryCache instance without adding the settings `ObjInfoCache = new MemoryCache("TestCache")`, which still returns Nothing.

I'm using .NET Framework 4

Comment: A constructor simply cannot return `Nothing`. A constructor creates an object and the only way it can not create an object is to throw an exception. Something else is going on.

Comment: By the way, are you aware that you can specify those limits in the config file and have the `Default` instance use them from there?

Comment: @jmcilhinney, yep, I've just found the config settings :) thx though. Still curious though why it doesn't work. Just created a new empty project in C# and it works flawlessly there. About the return; I meant it returned Nothing when calling a variable from the cache instance (the constructor was just there to show how I initialize the instance). Sorry if I was a bit vague about that. [Config file as reference for ppl who come here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/memorycache-element-cache-settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> About the return; I meant it returned Nothing when calling a variable from the cache instance

I suspect that you are creating multiple instance of the class that defines `ObjInfoCache.`

You have declared `ObjInfoCache` as `Shared`, thus its reference is common to all instances of the class.  However, you are initializing this reference in the class instance constructor (Public Sub New()).  Change the constructor to be `Shared` so that it only executes once when the type is referenced.

```
Shared Sub New()
    Dim CacheSettings As NameValueCollection = New NameValueCollection(3)
    CacheSettings.Add("CacheMemoryLimitMegabytes", 1024.ToString())
    CacheSettings.Add("physicalMemoryLimitPercentage", 50.ToString())
    CacheSettings.Add("pollingInterval", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2).ToString())
    ObjInfoCache = New MemoryCache("TestCache", CacheSettings)
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes that's it! Thanks very much. Can't believe I didn't notice that myself. Guess that because `MemoryCache.Default` worked it threw me on the wrong track, although it makes total sense now.